# Scala: importing object in the same file with a different name

Tags: scala, import, namespaces, rename

Lets say I have in the same file:

```
object x {
  case object z
}

object y {
  .. //want to internally refer to x.z as xxx.z
}
```

In other words I need to rename an import of an object in the same file.

currently I resort to:

```
object y {
  import x
  val xxx=x
  .. //referring to x.z as xxx.z
}
```

is there a better way of doing this? perhaps something along the lines of:

```
import .{x->xxx}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that for the proposes of what I was trying to do here, package object were really more appropriate as x only plays the role of organising the hierarchy. See [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html).

Answer (score 2):

In Scala, you can rename imports like this:

```
import package.{x => xxx}
```

See here for more details: http://blog.bruchez.name/2012/06/scala-tip-import-renames.html

EDIT: from comment below

If you are in the same file - you don't need to import anything:

```
object X {
  val a = 5
}

object Y {
  val x = X
  def p = println(x.a)
}

Y.p
```

Outputs

```
5
```

Comment: thanks. but I was hoping I would be able to avoid writing the full package name. is there any way of referring to the "current package"?

Comment: erm that's exactly what I have suggested in my actual question. I am seeking alternative approaches.

Comment: ShS - all Im saying is that you don't need the import from your example

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
package packagename

object x {
    case object z
}

object y {
    import packagename.{x => xxx}
    xxx.z
}
```

Note that you cannot import something that resides in the default package.